# Uninstall MacPorts without Port command working on Mac OS X 10.8.2

Tags: macos, macports

According to MacPorts' [wiki/guide](http://guide.macports.org/chunked/installing.macports.uninstalling.html) you need to have a working Port command but in my case the Port command isn't working.

How do I uninstall MacPorts?

I have tried Googling the solution but what I found is that someone said on some random discussion board that just skip Port command part and directly move onto the next one but some files will remain.

I have seen a lot of 'solutions' online but most of them ending with the user reinstalling MacPorts due to corrupted/failed installation. This isn't what I am looking for.

I don't want some files to remain, I want to clean it completely as I am not planning to reinstall MacPorts any time soon.

***By the way, I have HomeBrew installed, I hope the solution that you guys offers won't tamper with my HomeBrew installation.**

Thanks.

Comment: How exactly is your `port` command not working? What solutions did you already find (include links, please)?

Comment: @slhck when I type `port` in Terminal, it says command not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution myself. In order to get the `port` command to work, you must include it in your PATH variable or else the Terminal won't understand the command.

Open Terminal then type this
`open -e .bash_profile` then TextEdit will be opened with the .bash_profile loaded.

Add this code into the next line
`export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH`
Save your changes then type
`port` in Terminal to see if it is working.
Once you get the `port` command working then just follow the [uninstall guide](http://guide.macports.org/#installing.macports.uninstalling).

Source:
[MacPorts Guide](http://guide.macports.org/#installing.shell)

Comment: As you'll be removing MacPorts anyway, I'd suggest that instead of adding that line to your bash profile, just type it in the terminal window before running the uninstall procedure. It will add `port` to the path for the duration of that terminal session.

Answer (score 0):

There is an uninstall script on the MacPorts website. Run that. Then get the script to instal MacPorts.